# What was Duncan Idaho's Fremen name?

Tags: dune

I know Duncan Idaho spent time with the Fremen but I can't find the name the Fremen called him by.  I think it translated to He who fights with many blades.

Comment: I don't recall Idaho every having a Fremen name.

Comment: “Myown-private”

Comment: @Paulie_D - I've had a look in the books. encyclopaedia and various wiki articles. No mention is made of a Fremen name or nickname

Comment: @SillybutTrue - "*Donuts*"

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're referring to the fanfic [*The Unfinished Universe*](https://archiveofourown.org/works/35036536/chapters/88435648?view_adult=true) by foxflowering (note, NSFW).

He's referred to in the story as;

> "*Keifusu al-Raimjal.*” Paul glanced at Duncan, translating with a look of faint skepticism, “*The man of many blades?*”